# How to find complete string given multiple substrings of that string

Tags: python, machine-learning

I have a list of substrings of a story. They all start at the same place, but end at different points. This is my example input:

```
[
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud", 
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu",
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.", 
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. This is some extra text i don't care about"
]
```

It is like that except I have around 40 of them. My goal is to use machine learning and try and come up with one string that has the entire story, in this case this:

```
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
```

It doesn't need to be exact, I just need a way to extract it with the best accuracy.

I have tried just finding the longest substrings for each one of them, and trying to piece together those, but it wasn't successful. I need an algorithm of some sorts that will try and find what its guess of the story is.

I cannot just use the last string, since some strings have extra information in it as well.

Of the 40 strings I have, some are longer than the needed story and some are shorter. The shorter ones start from the beginning and end in the middle of the story. The longer ones start from the beginning, have the full story, and then at the end have other extra information that isn't needed. Each one of the longer ones extra information is unique (if it wasn't unique then it would be counted as part of the story)

Comment: But don't you already *have* the complete story? Isn't it just the last string in the array?

Comment: @ObsidianAge No since, some strings have extra information

Comment: My idea is to get the most appearing parts, the extra information won't be common

Comment: I think you have to think more on the problem description. How do you define "extra information"? If they all start at the same place, will the longest one always have some extra information? What about the second longest?

Comment: @Selcuk I have 40 strings, like I said in the description, some are longer then the needed string and some are shorter. The longer ones have gibberish at the end, and each longer one has different gibberish (if they had the same gibberish it would be part of the story)

Comment: @Selcuk It won't be the second longest either, i hope what i said above makes sense ^

Comment: @selcuk i have updated the description to match your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it (sentences shortened for readability):

```
stories = [
    "Lorem ipsum",
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. This is some extra text i don't care about",
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. A different gibberish this time.",
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur",
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.", # This is the full story
]

stories.sort(key=lambda s: len(s))

story = ""
for i, short_story in enumerate(stories[:-1]):
    for long_story in stories[i+1:]:
        if not long_story.startswith(short_story):
            break
    else:
        story = short_story

print(story)
```

output:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

Note that this code assumes that there is at least one story with gibberish at the end, otherwise it wouldn't work for the sample input in your question.

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to test it on my data I'll let you know the results in a few min

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked with 100% accuracy on my data :)

Comment: your new answer gives an empty string with my data.. I've used it in the same way. I think its because my data also has some extra gibberish strings that have nothing to do with anything in it

Comment: Keep this answer, as it answers the question the best, but i'll use your old one for my purposes

Comment: Hmm, I believe that could only happen if you have a very long string consisting of only whitespace. Is that the case?

Comment: Nope.. I have 40 normal strings, and then 3 strings that are 10 words long that are just random

Comment: Oh, but in this case the code works as expected. Your strings have no common start words, so the result is an empty string. My original code must've worked by accident.

Comment: Running the older one on those strings did work, interesting I guess

Comment: I'll try it on another one of my data sets.

Answer (score 0):

Sort them by ascending  size and do:

```
diff = strings[-1]
for part in strings[:-1]:
    diff = diff.lstrip(part)
print(strings[-1].rstrip(diff))
```

Comment: I upvoted this answer since it is a short way to achieve this, however this only got 160/239 words on my data. This is a very good solution, but it is probably related to my data that it isn't working. I have tried this with other samples and it works well

Comment: This is a cool way of doing it, but I guess it won't work if some gibberish parts start with the same words.

Comment: @Selcuk I think that's why it didn't work as well on my data, looks like a few of the gibberish do start with the same words

Comment: Yes, test with this input, for example: `strings = ["Full story", "Full story foo bar", "Full story foo baz", "Full story bar"]`. My answer had an issue with this example too, by the way (for a different reason), which should've been fixed now.

Comment: @Selcuk Did you mean to put the else with the if?

Comment: @SheshankS. No, it's a `for..else` block (it's a weird Python thing).

Comment: @Selcuk Oh interesting, I've never seen that before, I'm looking up how that works now

Comment: @selcuk; @shesank-s please change the following condition from the question: "Each one of the longer ones extra information is unique (if it wasn't unique then it would be counted as part of the story)".

Comment: @ipaleka I would still call them unique if they start with the same word(s) but the rest is different.

Comment: That makes them by definition the parts of the story.

Comment: @ipaleka Not necessarily, if there is a third story that has a different (completely unique) gibberish text.

Comment: That what you are saying is common sense, but even as such it doesn't pass given condition. I'm not trying to convince you that my answer is good, the only thing I want is that the condition changes and so enables passing of your common sense approach.